# How to save the double variables on an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Good day! I am trying to make a program that will ask the user to input the total number of the items. After the input of the total items, the program should ask the price of each item, based on the input. After the input of the prices, the program should compute the total price and ask for the cash. If the cash is not sufficient to pay the items, allow the user to re-enter cash until he/she inputted enough to pay the bill. Lastly, it will print the change of the user.

My problem is, how to I compute the price of each item. I think I need an array to save each prices and compute them afterwards. Here is my program, I know its a mess, sorry im still a beginner. Hoping for a solution. Thank you so much!!

```
public class Store {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner v = new Scanner (System.in);

        int totalitems;
        int change;
        int cash;
        double price[];
        double totalprice;

        System.out.print("Enter Total Number of Items: ");
        totalitems = v.nextInt();

        for(int loop=1; loop<=totalitems; loop++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the price of each item: ");
            price[totalitems] = v.nextInt();
        }

        //i need a solution here for array
        System.out.print("Enter the your cash: ");
        cash = v.nextInt();

        if(cash < totalprice) {
            System.out.print("Please input a sufficient amount: ");
            cash = v.nextInt();
        }else {
            change = cash - totalprice;
        }
        System.out.print("Thank you! Your change is: " + change);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the price array, either in the old-fashioned way:

```
for(int loop=0; loop < totalitems; loop++) {
    totalPrice = totalPrice + price[loop];
}
```

or, in the new way:

```
for (double itemPrice : price) {
    totalPrice = totalPrice + itemPrice;
}
```

But you're forgetting something else as well: the `price[]` array isn't initialized. As soon as the totalItems is known, you must do

```
price[] = new double[totalItems];
```

Otherwise Java wouldn't know how much memory to reserve for the array.